# issue in in fetching data by id while directly editing the url from url/posts/userId=1 to url/posts/userId=2

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

having a problem after getting the blogs of user1 on click of onClickUser(user) it is redirecting to url/posts?userId=1 and getting the blogs related to user1 also when i refresh the page the page is empty again and when i try editing the url to url/posts?userId=2 there itself without going back to the users page it is not showing any data. How to resolve this?

this is service.ts

```
  _currentUser = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentUser$ = this._currentUser.asObservable();

  _currentBlog = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  _currentBlog$ = this._currentBlog.asObservable();


  setCurrentUser(user) {
   this._currentUser.next(user);
  }

  setCurrentBlog(blog){
   this._currentBlog.next(blog)
  }

getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
return this.http.get<UserModel[]>(`${this._url}/users`)}

getUserBlogPosts(userId:number){
return this.http.get<BlogsModel[]>(`${this._url}/posts?userId=${userId}`)}
```

user.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.getUsersOnSubscribe()
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
  let id = params.get('id');
  console.log(id)
  if(id){
    this.getBlogsbyUserid(id)
  }
});
}
getBlogsbyUserid(id){
this.service.getUserBlogPosts(id).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('data getBlogsbyUserid')
    console.log(data)
    this.blogs = data
    this.service.setCurrentUser(this.blogs)
  }
)
}  
getUsersOnSubscribe(){
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  data =>{
    console.log(data);
    this.users = data;
  } 
)}
 onClickUser(users){  
this.currentUser = users
let id = users.id
console.log(id)        
this.service.getUserBlogPosts(id).subscribe(
  data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.currentUser = data
    this.service.setCurrentUser(this.currentUser)
  })  }
```

.blog.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.getBlogsList();  }

 getBlogsList() {
this.service.currentUser$.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.blogs = data
  }
)
}
```

Comment: did you check browser console for error

Comment: yeah it is showing null

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of component you can overwrite routeReuseStrategy as:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```